# Creating Masonry Layout

Tags: javascript, masonry

I am looking to build out a simple version of Masonry layout for an image gallery I am building. I wanted to use flexbox and utilize flex-direction columns and row wrap to create most of the layout.

The biggest feature I want to implement is customers are going to be able to set how many columns they want for the image gallery.

I want to calculate how tall the container will be with JavaScript so that when they select a different option such as 25%, 33% or 50% it will create the layout. I have a fairly simple version working but I want the gallery to be as symmetrical as possible. What I am doing now is finding the width of all of the images and then adding those together. Then I divide that number by the desired number of columns and then add that height to the masonry-container. Is this the best way to be finding how tall the container should be?

```
(function() {
  var width = 0;
  var curr_height = 0;
  var max_height = 0;

  $('.image-wrapper img').each(function() {
    width += $(this).width();
    curr_height = $(this).height();
     if (curr_height > max_height) {
       max_height = curr_height;
     }
  });

  var cols = 33.3333
  console.log(width, 'im the width')
  console.log(cols, 'im the num cols')
  console.log(max_height, 'im the max height')


  var containerHeight = (width * (cols / 100) - curr_height);
  console.log(containerHeight);


 $('.masonry-container').css('height', containerHeight);

})();
```

I created a JSFiddle here. 
    https://jsfiddle.net/Lzyg5mos/2/

Comment: Does the solution you are using here work? If so, the question *might* be better asked on [codereview.se], but I'd ask on their [meta.codereview.se] site.

Comment: Wouldn't this be much easier with CSS Grid and regions?

Comment: Yes, it would be. My main reason for trying to not use CSS Grid is I wanted to support IE11 which I know only support -prefixes currently

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [react-photo-gallery](https://github.com/neptunian/react-photo-gallery). It supports [column](https://codesandbox.io/s/r09k1xj614) or [row](https://codesandbox.io/s/9yx911wl9y) direction layouts.